Problem when using loop-generated variables in ansible
What i'm trying to do is generating lots of similar directory trees. I woul like to set a dict which describes the pattern of the tree. Then i want ansible to generate multiple directory trees with different indexes, generated from the special list.
Assume this simple playbook:
- hosts: [localhost]
  vars:
    instances: [1,2,3,4]
    dirs:
    - path: "/srvs/hosting{{ instance }}/dir1"
    - path: "/srvs/hosting{{ instance }}/dir2"
#   and so on ......

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item[1].path }}"
      loop: "{{ instances | product(dirs) | list }}"
      vars:
        instance: "{{ item[0] }}"

When using {{ instance }} var inside the 'path' var i'm getting an error:
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "[{'path': '/srvs/hosting{{ instance }}/dir1'}, {'path': '/srvs/hosting{{ instance }}/dir2'}]: {{ item[0] }}: 'item' is undefined"}
What i 'm expecting to get:
ok: [localhost] => (item=[1, {'path': '/srvs/hosting1/dir1'}]) => {
    "msg": {
        "path": "/srvs/hosting1/dir1"
    }
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[1, {'path': '/srvs/hosting1/dir2'}]) => {
    "msg": {
        "path": "/srvs/hosting1/dir2"
    }
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[2, {'path': '/srvs/hosting2/dir1'}]) => {
    "msg": {
        "path": "/srvs/hosting2/dir1"
    }
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[2, {'path': '/srvs/hosting2/dir2'}]) => {
    "msg": {
        "path": "/srvs/hosting2/dir2"
    }
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[3, {'path': '/srvs/hosting3/dir1'}]) => {
    "msg": {
        "path": "/srvs/hosting3/dir1"
    }
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[3, {'path': '/srvs/hosting3/dir2'}]) => {
    "msg": {
        "path": "/srvs/hosting3/dir2"
    }
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[4, {'path': '/srvs/hosting4/dir1'}]) => {
    "msg": {
        "path": "/srvs/hosting4/dir1"
    }
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[4, {'path': '/srvs/hosting4/dir2'}]) => {
    "msg": {
        "path": "/srvs/hosting4/dir2"
    }
}

What am i missing?

You are always welcome to provide a self answered question, but please do put that answer in an actual answer, not in your question.

Ok, thanks for pointing out

I managed to achieve my goal by rearranging {{ dirs }} without use of {{ instance }} as a part of path.
dirs:
- path: "dir1"
- path: "dir2"
   
tasks:
  - debug:
      msg: "/srvs/hosting{{ instance }}/{{ item[1].path }}"
    loop: "{{ instances | product(dirs) | list }}"
    vars:
      instance: "{{ item[0] }}"

